# advantage of using regular expressions over toString method for function decompilation in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function

John Resig used function decompilation technique in his [simple inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) example. His technique with regular expression method was also used in jQuery library and the same technique was criticized on opera blog. [On opera blog](http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/show.dml/1665828) some guy wrote:

> This is not a good idea because decompiling functions is an optional feature of the ES-262 spec. It is slow and requires too many resources for certain low-end platforms, so it is not supported by any of the Opera Mobile versions.

I'm well aware of **Function.prototype.toString** method and I also know about it's varying implementation by different browser vendors. So to come to my question:

**Is it possible to perform cross browser, reliable function decompilation at the current state?**

If yes which one of techniques I mentioned above should I use? And why?

Comment: What do you mean by "at the current state"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which one of techniques i mentioned above should i use?

There is only one technique, and that's the [`toString` method of functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString).

If you are using a regex and its `test` method, the argument will just implicitly be converted to a string - by calling its `toString` method.

Comment: toString seem to be an easy solution, so why John Resig decided to go (IMO) the hard way by hardcoding regex. I did't mentioned it above but my idea was to use either one of the methods to compare to identical functions (everything should the same except for white space and tabs) and toString gives exact implementation even white space is included, so what if i just used in first function to white space and in the second just one? would they give equal stings? === test would fail or not or should i just trim the whole white space characters and tabs with regex?

Comment: Functions can and should not be compared other than by reference. And he uses regex because he wants to test the code string against a regular expression, what else would you do ("so easy")?